# Excel Freeze Panes

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze

In past versions of Excel, I could freeze panes vertically or horizontally by moving my cursor to the edge of the spreadsheet until a small icon like this appeared:

<-||->

I could then drag the icon over (or down) to freeze the pane.  After that the symbol would appear when I put my cursor over the pane line and I could always drag it to adjust the location.

Now, in 365, the icon no longer appears on the edge.  It seems like the only way to do it is to go to "View-Freeze Panes" on the menu. Was this great feature really removed or was it perhaps an add-on or ...?   I still have an old spreadsheet with a frozen pane and I can still move that one around.  However, I can't create new ones.

Comment: I don't have an answer as I was never aware of the behaviour you describe. However, I have customised the Quick Access Toolbar to include "Freeze Panes" as one of the items, and I find that very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Upon further inspection, the feature is actually the "split" feature on the menu.  However, I have the same issue as I have to highlight a row/column and click on the menu rather than simply moving my cursor to the edge of the screen.

Comment: I had exactly the problem as you described and answered by DeerSpotter below.

Answer (score 1):

**Excel 2013 and Excel 2010**

When you work with a large Excel worksheet, it's often difficult to remember exactly what kind of data, columns or rows contain once you begin scrolling around the sheet.

**To freeze the top row or first column:**

1. From the **View** tab, **Windows Group**, click the **Freeze Panes** drop down arrow
2. Select either **Freeze Top Row** or **Freeze First Column**
3. Excel inserts a thin line to show you where the frozen pane begins

**To freeze several rows:**

1. Select the row that is immediately beneath the last row you want frozen
2. From the **View** tab, **Windows Group**, click the **Freeze Panes** drop down and select **Freeze Panes**
3. Excel inserts a thin line to show you where the frozen pane begins

**To freeze several column:**

1. Select the column that's immediately to the right of the last column you want frozen
2. Select the **View** tab, **Windows Grou**p, click the **Freeze Panes** drop down and select Freeze Panes
3. Excel inserts a thin line to show you where the frozen pane begins

**To freeze horizontal and vertical headings simultaneously:**

1. Select the cell in the upper-left corner of the range you want to remain scrollable
2. Select **View tab**, **Windows Group**, click **Freeze Panes** from the menu bar
3. Excel inserts two lines to indicate where the frozen panes begin

**To restore the workbook to its normal view:**

Select View tab, Windows Group, click Freeze Panes and select Unfreeze Panes

> (Shortcut key of Freeze panes: – Alt+W,F,F)
>
> Freeze panes:  Put the active cell in the desired location, and press
>   Alt+w and then F.  To remove the freeze panes, use the same shortcut.

**Also, there is a possibility that the freeze panes may have been disabled:**

[how to enable freeze panes link](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/what-to-do-when-the-freeze-panes-command-is-disabled-in-excel)

**The icon also appears, when you do a split on your windows:**
[image]

**link how to split windows:** [click me](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2016/freezing-panes-and-view-options/1/)

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question. The questioner knows how to freeze pains. The question asks about a shortcut that the questioner  believes to have been removed.

Comment: its the only way to do it now

Comment: @Blackwood. I disagree. I found this answer on SE and it exactly describes how to freeze - especially how to freeze multiple columns and rows simultaneously by clicking in the top-left corner of the scrollable area - I have not found that explanation anywhere else. Thank-you DeerSpotter