# How do you freeze rows A and B and columns 1 and 2 in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you freeze rows A and B and columns 1 and 2 in excel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Freeze Panes](https://superuser.com/questions/1386452/excel-freeze-panes)

Comment: @Thomas it actually does say so too, but for your convenience, I've spelled it out as a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You begin by setting the active cell to the first cell, top and left that you DO want to scroll.

Given that you want rows 1 and 2 to not scroll, this means the cursor moves to cell on row 3.

Given that you want columns A and B to not scroll, this means the cursor moves to column C.

So in order to select the right cell, you click on cell C3.

With this cell active, you now activate Freeze Panes (From the View tab, Windows Group, click the Freeze Panes drop down and select Freeze Panes), and it will freeze both the left side and the top side.